# How can I delete a file based on cell value?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble deleting a file based on cell value.
I get an error message on the line with the Kill command below:

```
Kill path & r.Offset(1, -4) & "\" & r.Offset(1, -3)
```

Any ideas?

```
Sub INACTIVE_files()

    Const path = "C:\Users\NikolouzosD\AppData\Local\Temp\vbakillfunction\"

    Dim r As Range
    Dim x As Integer

    Set r = Cells(1, 5)
    Do Until r = ""
        If UCase(r.value) = "INACTIVE" Then

            Kill path & r.Offset(1, -4) & "\" & r.Offset(1, -3)
          End If
          Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```

The code starts from cell E1 and looks for INACTIVE files in the same column, until there's no more files to look for.
Then, it checks the folder name (Column A), combines it with the Cube (Column B)
and puts both of them in a path:

```
path = "C:\Users\NikolouzosD\AppData\Local\Temp\vbakillfunction\"
```

so for example:
for cell E2 which is INACTIVE, the path should be:

```
C:\Users\NikolouzosD\AppData\Local\Temp\vbakillfunction\WPO 17 02 04 3MMT All Periods\BG023104.txt
```

It then deletes the INACTIVE files (Cubes) from the appropriate folder.

[image]

Comment: And after pasting the code in, highlight it all and hit the little `{}` button at the top so it's formatted properly. This way we can copy and paste to test and, more importantly, edit the code to post as an answer.

Comment: What does "error message on the path in the code" mean. Which line in the code generates the error and, more importantly, what is the error?

Comment: @Dimitri: Welcome to Stack Overflow: You aren't asking a [good, clear, concise question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion) Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question to include the code, expected behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your path in double quotes to avoid issues with spaces in filenames and folders.

Even better is to put the path in a string variable so you can debug it easily

**Outside your loop:**

```
Dim strPath As String
```

**Inside your if block:**

```
   strPath = """" & path & r.Offset(1,-4) & "\" & r.Offset(1,-3) & """"
   Debug.Print strPath ' Ctrl-G to view results
   Kill strPath
```

**EDIT - add a check for file before deleting**

Under `Tools | References`

Add a reference to Windows Script Hosting

Then at top of sub code add

```
Dim fso as New FileSystemObject
```

Replace your Kill command with a check for existence

```
If fso.FileExists(strPath) Then
   Kill strPath
Else
   Msgbox "File Doesn't Exist: " & strPath
End If
```

**UPDATED FOR CONTINUE TO NEXT FILE**

Change loop to be:

```
Do Until r = ""
   If UCase(r.value) = "INACTIVE" AND fso.FileExists(strPath) Then
        Kill strPath
   End If
   Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response. I'm still getting an error on the "Kill strPath" command though. The message i get in the immediate window is:  "C:\Users\NikolouzosD\AppData\Local\Temp\vbakillfunction\WPO 17 02 04 3MMT All Periods\BG023105.txt"

Comment: Like @Jnevill said - what is the error?  Perhaps you should be checking for file existence before trying to delete it?. Another thing to check is if file is locked

Comment: I found what the problem was: the first time it runs, it deletes the appropriate files that are INACTIVE. When I run it again, I get an error that those files are missing, which is true. So, how could we bypass it saying: if a file doesn't exist, move to the next cell and loop the same procedure ?

Comment: Updated answer to show how to modify your loop with new code using `FileExists` logic

Comment: Thanks a lot @dbmitch!

Comment: Thanks - please mark it as an answer if it fits - or upvote it if you feel it helped in anyway. You can put edit your question and add your alternative version - or leave as is and mark your own as an answer later

Answer (score 0):

It works!
I've commented out some parts of the code that were used for checking if a file exists.

```
 Sub delete_INACTIVE_files()


Const path = "C:\Users\Dn\AppData\Local\Temp\vbakillfunction\"
Dim r As Range


Set r = Cells(1, 5)

Do Until r = ""


    If UCase(r.Value) = "INACTIVE" Then

        If Dir(path & r.Offset(0, -4) & "\" & r.Offset(0, -3) & ".txt") <> "" Then 'Does the file exist?

            'MsgBox "file" & path & r.Offset(0, -4) & "\" & r.Offset(0, -3) & ".txt" & " exists"

            Kill path & r.Offset(0, -4) & "\" & r.Offset(0, -3) & ".txt"


        'Else

            'MsgBox "file" & path & r.Offset(0, -4) & "\" & r.Offset(0, -3) & ".txt" & " not here"


        End If

    End If

    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)

Loop

End Sub
```