# How can I delete pdf files when sums to zero

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to see if there is a way to delete a pdf file when the row balances to zero. I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51481681/how-can-i-delete-a-file-based-on-cell-value) but I could not get it to work for me, any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Goals

- Delete pdf file if Column N5 balances to zero if exists, pdf is named after RGN in A5 usually
- Loop through all the rows and until it reaches the end
- Bonus would be to account for wildcard naming since sometimes the pdf could be RGN_649610.pdf

Example 649610.pdf should be deleted when N5 balances to 0 as shown in the image.

```
C:.
│   TES_123.xlsx
│
└───Scanned
    ├───DIR1
    │       649610.pdf
    │       649615.pdf
    │
    └───DIR2
            649612.pdf
            649617.pdf
```

[Excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NybLn.png)

Code I tried

```
Sub delete_INACTIVE_files()
Const path = "C:\Users\bmh\Desktop\TES 123\"
Dim r As Range
Set r = Cells(5, 14)
Do Until r = ""
    If UCase(r.Value) = "0" Then
        If Dir(path & "Scanned" & "\DIR1" & "\" & r.Offset(0, -13) & ".pdf") <> "" Then
            Kill path & "Scanned" & "\DIR1" & "\" & r.Offset(0, -13) & ".pdf"
        End If
    End If
    Set r = r.Offset(5, 0)
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to include the code you tried, and say what specific problems you had with it.  Please see [ask] and consider editing your question.

Comment: Updated the main post to include code i've been trying to use, it works to delete the pdf file when I hard code the paths now but is there a way to account for different sub folder names? wildcard perhaps?

Comment: Do you know which subdirectory (Dir1, DIR2, etc) the file will be in?  Is there always only a single match for each id?

Comment: Typically yes but there is 5 different folders depending on what type of product it is so I need a way to have to recursively search each for the file and delete when found.

Comment: There's nothing in the data which would tell you which subfolder?  How many files in total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub delete_INACTIVE_files()
    Const PATH = "C:\Users\bmh\Desktop\TES 123\Scanned\"
    Dim r As Range, ws As Worksheet, id, n, f, files As Collection, fName
    
    Set files = GetMatches(PATH, "*.pdf") 'find all files in the folder/subfolders
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set r = ws.Cells(5, 14)
    Do While Len(r.Value) > 0
        If r.Value = 0 Then
            id = ws.Cells(r.Row, "A").Value 'get the Region
            'find any matching files and delete them
            For n = files.Count To 1 Step -1
                Set f = files(n)
                fName = UCase(f.Name)
                If fName = id & ".PDF" Or _
                   fName = "RGN_" & id & ".PDF" Then
                    f.Delete        'delete the file
                    files.Remove n  'remove from the collection
                End If
            Next n
        End If
        Set r = r.Offset(1, 0) 'next row
    Loop
End Sub

'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder
    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1
        For Each f In fldr.files
            If UCase(f.Name) Like UCase(filePattern) Then colFiles.Add f
        Next f
        If subFolders Then
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.PATH
            Next subFldr
        End If
    Loop
    Set GetMatches = colFiles
End Function
```

Comment: This works, the .pdf file are added by users and change often so when I receive a credit and balance the row I can delete the .pdf as they are no longer needed at that point. Your solution is working perfectly, I'm going to see if I can follow its logic to better understand how your accomplished this.

Comment: The only other question I would have is can I change PATH = to something that picks up the location of the excel file? such as ThisWorkbook.Path?

Comment: Maybe `ThisWorkbook.Path & “\scanned\”`

Comment: Compile error: Constant expression required. I will continue to google and see what I can find.

Comment: Sorry you can't do that as a Constant - make it a regular variable.